# Creating new PostGIS connection in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, connection

I am trying to create a new PostGIS connection and I am doing as it follows:

[image]

The password I inserted is postgres, I don't know what should be inserted there. And when testing the connection, I get this as a response:

[image]

What do you suggest me to do?

Comment: Try "admin" or leaving it blank.

Comment: I have tryied but is not working.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the db outside Q in pgAdmin or something else?

Comment: Yes, I am connected to it in pgAdmin.

Comment: In the file `pg_hba.conf`, you can change the authentification from `md5` to `trust` to avoid the password checking.

Answer (score -1):

enter postresql with:

```
$ psql
$ \password postgres   #or any account to change pass on
```