# PostGIS connection in QGIS using Linux login-user?

Tags: qgis, postgis

I wanted to set up a **generic** QGIS project (with PostGIS data on `localhost`) that can be re-used by different users. I use `trust authentication`, so no need to worry about passwords.

The problem is that I still have to provide a user name when creating a local PostGIS connection in QGIS, which is stored in the QGIS project (`.qgs`) file. (I use the current login-user in Linux). The project file becomes unusable/invalid when a different user tries to use my project file on their machines.

Is there a way to set up the project (or system) so that it works for any Linux user name, assuming those users have default PostgreSQL databases/usernames, which are the same name as their OS user names?

Related:
[Creating new PostGIS connection in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165070)

(I'm using QGIS3, PostGIS 2.4).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From tests with QGIS 3, QGIS allows creating a PostGIS connection to `localhost` without database and user names. Just leave them empty. And QGIS will use the default values such as the Linux login user name (or the environmental variables: `PGUSER` and `PGDATABASE`).